# Using ‘each’ in a correct way

Tags: each-every

1. I gave children one toy
2. I gave children one toy each
3. I gave each child one toy

Do all of sentences above make the same sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second and third choices are equivalent, but the first states you gave *all* the children a *single* toy to share. An article is also missing, e.g., "I gave *the* children one toy." The third sentence is most clear.